# C# program to communicate with a xbee module using COM Ports / Using USB Serial COM Port

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working a c# program which use the usb serial COM Port to transmit and receive data. The component is XBEE module which I want ot access but the code I wrote dosen't detect any serial port on my Computer. Any one who can help me rectifying my mistake.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Test : Form
    {
        private StringBuilder receivedData = new StringBuilder();

        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Array ports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            for (int x = 0; x <= ports.Length; comboBox1.Items.Add(ports.GetValue(x))) ;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Test_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Write(textBox2.Text + "\n\r");
            }
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            receivedData.Append(serialPort1.ReadExisting());
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = receivedData.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried https://code.google.com/p/xbee-api-sharp/ ? this works out of the box for me with my Xbee modules

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the correct parameters on the serial port to match the settings of the device. Have you installed [XCTU](http://knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/X-CTU-XCTU-software)? Take note of the settings in the "search for devices" dialog - assuming it does find your device!

[image: The XCTU Discover Devices dialog]

For me, I found I actually just needed to set the baud rate:

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort(portName);
serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
serialPort.Open();
// win!
```